# OrderBy com ng-repeat aninhado no angularJS

Tags: angularjs, classificação, ng-repeat

Preciso ordenar um lista, que está dentro de dois `ng-repeat`, mas só consigo ordenar dentro do grupo do segundo `ng-repeat` e fiz um `jsFiddle` que mostra o meu código:

https://jsfiddle.net/xxg4ajkk/2/

A ordem que eu quero que funcione é como no exemplo abaixo.

> Ordenado por nome:

```
Alberto Alexandre - 2º Ciclo - prata
João Alfredo - 1º Ciclo - bronze
Maria Tomazio - 1º Ciclo - prata
Roxele Almondega - 2º Ciclo - ouro
```

> Ordenado por ciclo:

```
João Alfredo - 1º Ciclo - bronze
Maria Tomazio - 1º Ciclo - prata
Alberto Alexandre - 2º Ciclo - prata
Roxele Almondega - 2º Ciclo - ouro
```

> Ordenado por plano:

```
Roxele Almondega - 2º Ciclo - ouro
Maria Tomazio - 1º Ciclo - prata
Alberto Alexandre - 2º Ciclo - prata
João Alfredo - 1º Ciclo - bronze
```

Comment: Deu certo alguma das respostas?

Comment: Acabei pedindo para mudarem o JSON sem aninhar por ciclo. As duas respostas estão excelentes, e vão me ajudar muito, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você irá precisar criar um outro template de exibição devido ser array aninhado. No caso do plano, como a ordem é semântica, irá precisar usar um peso para cada plano.

*Concatenando os associados:*

```
$scope.redeExibir = [].concat.apply([], $scope.minhaRede.attributes.rede.map((mapa) => {
    return mapa.associados.map((asso) => {
        asso.ciclo = mapa.ciclo;
        asso.plano = $scope.planos[asso.plano];
        return asso;
    })
}));
```

Filtro para exibir os planos conforme peso:

```
app.filter('plano', function() {
    let planos = {
        'ouro': 1,
        'prata': 2,
        'bronze': 3
    };
    return function(input) {
        for (let prop in planos) {
            if (planos[prop] == input) return prop;
        }
    }
});
```

**Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/xxg4ajkk/3/**

Answer (score 2):

Quando precisa orderna uma lista de valores e eles estão em chaves diferentes, precisa formatar o layout para uma novo, então, a proposta inicial é criar um novo `array` com a chave `associados`, ***exemplo***:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('minhaRede', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.sortBy = function(field) {
        $scope.predicate = field;
      }
      $scope.predicate = "nome_usuario"; // ordenação padrão
      $scope.minhaRede = {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "usuario-redes",
        "attributes": {
          "rede": [{
            "ciclo": 1,
            "associados": [{
              "nome_usuario": "João Alfredo",
              "plano": "bronze",
              "associado_situacao": "Ativo",
              "quem_indicou": "thaylon_lomonte",
              "created_at": "2017-05-17T18:03:03.810-03:00"
            }, {
              "nome_usuario": "Maria Tomazio",
              "plano": "prata",
              "associado_situacao": "Ativo",
              "quem_indicou": "thaylon_lomonte",
              "created_at": "2017-05-18T18:03:03.810-03:00"
            }]
          }, {
            "ciclo": 2,
            "associados": [{
              "nome_usuario": "Alberto Alexandre",
              "plano": "prata",
              "associado_situacao": "Ativo",
              "quem_indicou": "joao_alfredo",
              "created_at": "2017-05-21T18:03:03.810-03:00"
            }, {
              "nome_usuario": "Roxele Almondega",
              "plano": "ouro",
              "associado_situacao": "Ativo",
              "quem_indicou": "joao_alfredo",
              "created_at": "2017-05-20T18:03:03.810-03:00"
            }]
          }]
        }
      }
      //criação de uma lista formatada
      $scope.lista = function() {
        $associados = [];
        var rede = $scope.minhaRede.attributes.rede;
        angular.forEach(rede, function(item) {
          for (i = 0; i < item.associados.length; i++) {
            item.associados[i]['ciclo'] = item.ciclo + 'º Ciclo';
            item.associados[i]['seq'] =
              item.associados[i].plano == "ouro" ? 1 :
              (item.associados[i].plano == "prata" ? 2 : 3);
            $associados.push(item.associados[i]);
          }
        });
        return $associados;
      };
    }
  ])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="minhaRede">
    <div class="button-bar">
      <button ng-click="sortBy('nome_usuario')">Nome</button>
      <button ng-click="sortBy('seq')">Plano</button>
      <button ng-click="sortBy('ciclo')">Ciclo</button>
    </div>
    predicate: {{predicate}}
    <br><br>
    <div>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="associado in lista() | orderBy:predicate" style="border: 1px solid silver;">
        <b>{{associado.nome_usuario}}</b> - {{associado.ciclo}} - {{associado.plano}}<br>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```